# mod_rewrite Configuration for All Subdirectories

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

In Apache HTTPD 2.2, I want to make it so requests for `/index.foo` or `/foo`, if they aren't files or directories, become `/index.php?transform=foo`, regardless of how many levels the URL has.

Criteria for success would be:

- `http://www.site.example/index.foo` -> `http://www.site.example/index.php?transform=foo`
- `http://www.site.example/foo` -> `http://www.site.example/index.php?transform=foo`
- `http://www.site.example/bar/baz/foo` -> `http://www.site.example/bar/baz/index.php?transform=foo`

I.e., I don't want rewrites to be relative to the .htaccess directory; I want them to be relative to the topmost directory in the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using two modified versions of the regex from [this page](http://techtavern.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/regex-that-matches-path-filename-and-extension/):

```
# $1 = directory, $2 = extension
# Matches:
# - /html
# - /web/portfolio/html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?(html|rss|txt)$ $1index.php?transform=$2 [L]

# $1 = directory, $2 = "index.", $3 = extension
# Matches:
# - /index.html
# - /web/portfolio/index.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?(?:$|(index\.)(?:([^.]*$)|$))$ $1$2php?transform=$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Check if file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f

# Rewrite the URI if file doesn't exist and contains "index."
RewriteRule ^(.*)(index\.[^/]+)$ $1/index.php?transform=$2 [L]

# The same thing for any other URI
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/]+)$ $1/index.php?transform=$2 [L]
```

Comment: Reaults in a 500 Error.

Comment: Check your error log and activate `RewriteLog` to find out what causes the error.

Comment: At first it said "bad flag delimiters". I deleted the space after the exclamation points and that allowed me to access the site root, but as soon as I tried to access `/foo` I got another 500, with this in the log:

"Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace."

Comment: There's a ton in the rewrite log but here's the first few lines (with sensitive info replaced), "foo" in this case being "html":

`127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/user/Sites/site/html -> html
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] applying pattern '^(.*)(index\.[^/]+)$' to uri 'html'`

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] strip per-dir prefix: /Users/user/Sites/site/html -> html
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] applying pattern '^(.*)([^/]+)$' to uri 'html'
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (4) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] RewriteCond: input='/Users/user/Sites/site/html' pattern='!-f' => matched`

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (2) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] rewrite 'html' -> 'htm/index.php?transform=l'
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (3) split uri=htm/index.php?transform=l -> uri=htm/index.php, args=transform=l
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (3) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] add per-dir prefix: htm/index.php -> /Users/user/Sites/site/htm/index.php`

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (2) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] strip document_root prefix: /Users/user/Sites/site/htm/index.php -> /htm/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Nov/2010:21:14:31 --0500] [site.example/sid#1008e2800][rid#1009b7e98/initial] (1) [perdir /Users/user/Sites/site/] internal redirect with /htm/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]`